# How do I fill an animated shape with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapely

I would like to plot two arbitrary polygons (using shapely for calculation of area, intersection as I am not aware of another method) and then fill the intersection, and shapes as they intersect and move during the animation.

After searching I cannot figure out how to implement this.

I have reviewed:

- set_fill
- matplotlib artists documentation reference
- fill_between
- animation
- add_patch

However, I believe I must be missing something fundamental here, or possibly it does not support filling objects during animation as the only filled object examples I can locate are static graphs.

Example code (minimum example, with two shapely shapes) is below, and has been tested as functional with python 3.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapely.geometry as sg
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

xdata, ydata = [],[]
x2data, y2data = [],[]

ln, = plt.plot([],[])
ln2, = plt.plot([],[])

def init():
    ax.axis('equal')
    ax.set_xlim(-4, 4)
    ax.set_ylim(-4, 4)
    return ln,ln2,
 
def update(frame):
    fig.text(0,0, 'hello')
    circ1 = sg.Point(frame-2,0).buffer(1.0)
    circ2 = sg.Point(-frame+2,0).buffer(1.0)

    x,y = circ1.exterior.xy
    x2,y2 = circ2.exterior.xy
    
    intersection = circ1.intersection(circ2)
    
    xdata.append(x)
    ydata.append(y)
     
    x2data.append(x2)
    y2data.append(y2)

    ln.set_data(x,y)
    ln2.set_data(x2,y2)
    
    return ln,ln2,
  
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2, 200),
                    init_func=init, blit=True, interval = 10)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are working with Polygons, I would suggest you use [matplotlib's `Polygon`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Polygon.html?highlight=polygon#matplotlib-patches-polygon) instead of a line to draw your shapes. This allows you to get the coordinates of the intersection shape, and draw the corresponding polygon with whatever color you choose:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapely.geometry as sg
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

poly1 = Polygon(np.zeros(shape=(0, 2)), facecolor='none', edgecolor='C0')
poly2 = Polygon(np.zeros(shape=(0, 2)), facecolor='none', edgecolor='C1')
intersect = Polygon(np.zeros(shape=(0, 2)), facecolor='C2', edgecolor='none')

ax.add_artist(poly1)
ax.add_artist(poly2)
ax.add_artist(intersect)
t = ax.text(0.5, 0.9, "frame = ", transform=ax.transAxes, ha='center')


def init():
    ax.axis('equal')
    ax.set_xlim(-4, 4)
    ax.set_ylim(-4, 4)
    return poly1, poly2, t


def update(frame):
    t.set_text(f'frame = {frame:.3f}')
    circ1 = sg.Point(frame - 2, 0).buffer(1.0)
    circ2 = sg.Point(-frame + 2, 0).buffer(1.0)

    x, y = circ1.exterior.xy
    x2, y2 = circ2.exterior.xy

    intersection = circ1.intersection(circ2)

    poly1.set_xy(np.c_[x, y])
    poly2.set_xy(np.c_[x2, y2])

    if len(intersection.exterior.coords)>0:
        x3, y3 = intersection.exterior.coords.xy
        intersect.set_xy(np.c_[x3, y3])
        intersect.set_visible(True)
    else:
        intersect.set_visible(False)

    return poly1, poly2, intersect, t


ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2, 200),
                    init_func=init, blit=True, interval=10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You first need to make a fill object by:

```
fill = ax.fill_between(xdata, ydata, 0, color='cyan')
```

Then, access the PolyCollection Class and update its vertice in the animation function by using

```
def animation(t):
    path = fill.get_paths()[0]
    verts = path.vertices
    # change vertice in numpy array hereof
    verts[1:-1, 1][0:2] = np.array([x, x, x])
    fill.set_color('cyan')
    return line
```